Ergodicity for the second return map of an irrational rotation
Let $q$ be an irrational and consider T to be the rotation by $q$ in the interval $[0,1)$. This is uniquely ergodic. Consider its first return map $T^{r_1}$ to the subinterval $[0,q)$. This is also ergodic (uniquely ergodic I think).
Consider $T^{r_2}$ to be the second return map to the interval $[0,q)$. Meaning $T^{r_2}(x)=T^n(x)$ where $n$ is the smallest integer such that the orbit $x,T(x),...T^n(x)$ has visited $[0,q)$ exactly twice. Is $T^{r_2}$ ergodic?
In general if T is ergodic the second return map is not ergodic. I am wondering that in the case of an irrational rotation if it is true.

Just in case someone was interested,  I was thinking on the following:
The first return map of the irrational rotation respect $q$ to the subinterval $[0,q)$ is a uniquely ergodic interval exchange transformation of two intervals, hence  a rotation by irrational angle again. This transformation  $g$ is totally ergodic. The second return map to $[0,q)$ corresponds to the interval exchange transformation $h(x)=g^2(x)$ which, therefore its ergodic. More general the $n$-th return time to this subinterval will be the transformation $g^n$ which is uniquely ergodic. In particular the return time to this subinterval is totally ergodic.
For more general return time maps for other subintervals, following the same idea and a theorem of Veech says that almost any interval exchange transformation is totally ergodic, this means that the $n$-th return map to that subinterval is almost sure  ergodic.
